# Setting value for Omitted Field in Autoform in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-autoform

When using a `quickform` from the `aldeed:autoform` package, how can we set the value of a field that we have omitted using `omitFields`? That field is omitted because we do not want the user to change its default value (eg: changing userId from `Meteor.userId()`) nor see that field.

Example:

```
{{> quickForm collection="Contacts" id="contacts-new-form" type="insert" omitFields="avatarUrl,details.active" buttonContent="Create Contact"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to omit fields, but provide default values for that field, you should be using `autovalue` as documented at https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#autovalue

Alternatively, you can define your autoform attributes in your schema definition and keep them together as detailed here:

https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#putting-field-attribute-defaults-in-the-schema

If this is an update form and you are not looking for an autovalue, but rather keep the original value, then you can alternatively make that specific field a hidden input field as described at https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2#problems so that it can still pass validation.

But I'd go with solid autovalue definitions.

Comment: And how exactly do we access some template data like avatarUrl in autovalue?

Comment: You cannot access template data from within a collection2 instance because it runs on both client *and* the server where template is *not* available. So you need to access where the data actually is. If avatarURL is part of the user information, you access user directly. `Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).profile.avatarUrl` would perhaps work for you!

Comment: Ok. And to add other client side stuff, we would use hooks? Like in below answer?

Comment: You should use autovalue for that. Read the collection2 docs.

Answer (score 0):

@Nyxynyx You need to add this code. just use hook and add userId using before insertion. Look at the below example i hope this will help you.

```js
var postHooks = {
  before: {
    insert: function(doc) {
      if(Meteor.userId()){
        doc.userId = Meteor.userId();
      }
      
      return doc;
    }
  }
}
```